# AsyncImage with a placeholder sizing to fit to aspect ratio and clipping

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-asyncimage

I'm trying to create an `AsyncImage` with a placeholder image. With the following constraints...

1. The placeholder image may not have the same aspect ratio as the `AsyncImage`.
2. The remote image may not have the same aspect ratio as the `AsyncImage`.
3. The remote and placeholder image may not have the same aspect ratios.
4. The aspect ratio of the `AsyncImage` is fixed.

The requirements...

1. The placeholder and the remote image must be scaled to fill the aspect ratio of the `AsyncImage`.
2. They must not be squashed.
3. They must be clipped so that they do not overflow the bounds of the `AsyncImage` (set by the aspect ratio).

In my head this should be simple.

But I just cannot get this to work without at least one of the requirements breaking.

This is the closest I've got so far but the `AsyncImage` is just not clipped so overflows beyond either the height or width.

You can paste this into Xcode and it will show the

```
import SwiftUI

let aspect = 1.5

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        AsyncImage(
            url: URL(string: "https://placekitten.com/1920/1080"),
            transaction: .init(animation: .easeIn(duration: 3)) // <- slow animation to show issue
        ) { phase in
            switch phase {
            case .success(let image):
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fill)
                    .clipped()

            default:
                Image(systemName: "rectangle")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fill)
                    .clipped()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fill)
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            TestView()
                .overlay {
                    // This overlay shows the correct rect but the image is just not cclipped.
                    Color.black
                        .opacity(0.5)
                        .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fit)
                }
                .padding()
                .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fit)
        }
        .background(Color.red)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This gives me the following...

[image]

The red background is from the VStack. The black transparent overlay shows the aspect ratio I'm looking for based on the `aspect` set at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using a geometry reader to set the height and width of the image container?

You can use this to work out the required ratio. That's the approach I would take.

Comment: In the end just wrapping in a geometry reader gave me the size without me having to calculate anything myself :D Thanks

Comment: I have a setup like this, but that geometry reader seems to be responsible for nearby buttons not to work any more. Do you have any idea on that one?