How to make an image fill the screen and be centered in SwiftUI
I want to display an AsyncImage that fills the screen and also centers the image. Here's an example, but it's top-leading aligned.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/v/home/bn/images/promos/ipad-air/promo_ipadair_announce__eqsaj3vip4om_large_2x.jpg")) { image in
            image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        } placeholder: {
            ProgressView()
        }
    }
}


Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76720697/asyncimage-with-a-placeholder-sizing-to-fit-to-aspect-ratio-and-clipping/76721036?noredirect=1#comment138301979_76721036

The image is not aligned top-leading, but it's not centered either. This is how it looks when running on an iPhone 15 simulator running iOS 17.5 (Xcode 15.4):

This particular image is quite wide, but the main subject is pretty well centered horizontally, so when scaled to fill it should be seen to be horizontally centered.
Here are two ways to get it working:
1. Set the screen size as frame size
A GeometryReader can be used to measure the size of the screen and this size can then be applied as a .frame to the image:
GeometryReader { proxy in
    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/v/home/bn/images/promos/ipad-air/promo_ipadair_announce__eqsaj3vip4om_large_2x.jpg")) { image in
        image
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
    } placeholder: {
        ProgressView()
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea()

2. Alternatively, apply the image as an overlay to a full-screen view
The modifier .ignoresSafeArea needs to be applied after the overlay:
Color.clear
    .overlay {
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/v/home/bn/images/promos/ipad-air/promo_ipadair_announce__eqsaj3vip4om_large_2x.jpg")) { image in
            image
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        } placeholder: {
            ProgressView()
        }
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea()

The result is the same in both cases:

